# How to skip specific days using auto_arima

Tags: pandas, dataframe, arima

I'm trying to forecast using (auto_arima) excluding specific days.

Code:

```
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima

df = pd.read_csv('devices_transactions_count.csv')

def remove_holidays(date, transactions):
    if date in ['2019-06-03', '2019-06-04', '2019-06-05', '2019-06-06', '2019-06-07', '2019-06-08', '2019-06-09',
                       '2019-08-08', '2019-08-09', '2019-08-10', '2019-08-11', '2019-08-12', '2019-08-13','20199-08-14',
                       '2019-08-15', '2019-08-16']:
        return None
    else:
        return transactions
df['transactions'] = df.index.map(lambda i: remove_holidays(df.date.iloc[i], df.transactions.iloc[i]))
df.head()

train = df[df.date < '2019-09-20']
train.to_csv('train.csv')
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
del train['Unnamed: 0']
train.head()

train['transactions'] = train['transactions'].astype('float32')
train['date'].replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace='M', value='')
train['date'] = pd.to_datetime(train['date'], format='%Y%m', errors='ignore', infer_datetime_format=True)
train = train.set_index(['date'])


decomposition = auto_arima(train.transactions, start_p=1, start_q=1,
                           max_p=3, max_q=3, m=12,
                           start_P=0, seasonal=True,
                           d=1, D=1, trace=True,
                           error_action='ignore',  
                           suppress_warnings=True, 
                           stepwise=True)
```

This will throw th following error: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite your cleaning function to a list lookup:

```
skip_days = ['2019-06-03', '2019-06-04', '2019-06-05', '2019-06-06', '2019-06-07', '2019-06-08', '2019-06-09','2019-08-08', '2019-08-09', '2019-08-10', '2019-08-11', '2019-08-12', '2019-08-13','20199-08-14','2019-08-15', '2019-08-16']

# Exclude these days
df_filtered = df[~df['date'].isin(skip_days)]
```

This will exclude these values from the dataframe allowing your dataset to be clear from nan/null values.